# Why jQuery scripts doesn't work when put scripts above jquery liberary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code works:

```
<div class="demo-gallery" data-pswp-uid="1">            
<a class = "delete_button">click</a>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        { 
            $(".delete_button").click( function (event) { 
                event.preventDefault(); 
                  alert('hi');
                  return false; 
             });
        });
    </script>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zqdpfvzo/

but not works if I put script under `jquery-2.1.4.js`:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zqdpfvzo/1/

why and how can Fixed it?

Comment: Because scripts are executed/parsed/loaded in the other they appear in the html.Browers cannot time travel, and will not jump back in time to retroactively run the script that couldn't be run because jquery wasn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because the scripts load in the order that they are declared.  In the second demo, the in-page code attempts to run before jQuery has been defined and loaded, thus errors out and does nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just like the way you can not use the value of a variable before declaring and initializing it, the same way you need to declare and initialize the variable `jQuery` first, then only you can use it properties.

The scripts are being loaded in browser syncronously in the same order in which they are written.

**Trying to do a analogy:**

Issue is:

```
alert(x);
var x = 5;
```

Fix is:

```
var x = 5;
alert(x);
```